# removing mediawiki languages from a standard installation?

Tags: wiki, mediawiki

How doe i go about removing other mediawiki languages from a standard installation?

---

is it enough to delete the folder? does that cause harm??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can force users to use only one language. See [this document](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgLanguageCode#Disable_user_selection_of_language) for instructions.